# Dell Optiplex 780 add on video not functioning

Tags: graphics-card

I have tried both the FirePro 3D Graphics V4800 (this one was working previously) and the ATI Radeon HD 5450 1GB. But when I put the Radeon HD 5450 in, I get this:
Attention: Unsupported Video Configuration Detected

Action is Required

This computer has an add-in graphics card, but the monitor cable is plugged
into the integrated video connector.
To attach the monitor cable to the add-in graphics card:

1. Shut down the computer
2. Plug the monitor cable into the add-in graphics card connector.
   This may require a video adapter or video adapter cable.
   (provided with system)
3. Turn on the computer.

This message should not appear after completing these steps.
For more information or help, please refer to the system documentation.
System halted!
Just as information, I unplugged the drive in SATA-0 and I get a squarish 0 with a dot in the middle instead of one with no dot and more round.

Comment: Please [edit] and post the exact discret graphics card you added. Also https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/optiplex_780_tech_guidebook_en.pdf p.12 lists the few cards Dell recommends (and sells). It should work with others but not all.

Comment: Try to disable the on-board video and plug in the card, and then see if the card works and get the drivers installed, etc. Look over the built-in video type as I vaguely recall there being an issue if the chipset it AMD and the card is... uh, of another make video drivers (e.g. Nvidia), etc. or vice versa if you know what I'm saying. I don't recall exactly what I used to do to resolve but play with some ideas from that and the disabling on-board videa from BIOS and trying some of the various configurations, etc. Once drivers are installed, test further too...

Comment: I tried disabling and that's how I get the error. And I can't get drivers installed because there are no BIOS drivers for it AFAIK. It works enough to give the error, but not past that.